# Why am I receiving an InvalidCastException here?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, casting

I have the following two classes:

```
    public class Foo : IFooOperations
    {
        public FooData Data { get; set; }
        public FooUser User { get; set; }

        public Foo(FooData fooData)
        {
            Data = fooData;
        }

        private async void SetupFoo()
        {
            ...
        }

        public async void FooOp()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

and

```
    public class Bar : Foo, IBarOperations
    {

        public Foo(FooData fooData) : base(fooData)
        {
        }

        public async void BarOp()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

After I've been given a `Foo` object, why does `Bar bar = (Bar)foo;` not allow me to cast this to a `Bar` object? It throws an `InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.` exception instead.

In my mind, this ought to work. `Bar` is just `Foo` with a single additional method operating on state which is already common to both objects.

Some additional context: the `Bar` objects are essentially privileged `Foo` users who, based on their data, are permitted to access the `BarOp()` method. I'm building an SDK and want to (ab)use the cast mechanism to hide these privileged methods by default. I want my end user to need to make the conscious decision that the `Foo` is indeed a `Bar` and perform the cast before they are able to access the `BarOp()` method.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be wrong, how I might fix this, or alternative architectures to consider?

Comment: It has to do with the fact that Bar also implements IBarOperations, which is not a thing for Foo

Comment: As an aside, do you actually have a lot of async void methods? I'd strongly recommend against that - make them return `Task` if you possibly can. I realize this may not *actually* be representative of your code.

Comment: Ah, thank you! Seems like such a silly thing to have missed here in retrospect. And @JonSkeet don't worry, those are all actually Tasks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bar is just Foo with a single additional method operating on state which is already common to both objects.

That's completely irrelevant to whether or not a cast will work. A cast (between reference types, ignoring user-defined conversions) can only succeed in .NET if the object that's referred to *is* an instance of the target type, or some child type. It's that simple. You could have two classes without *any* extra members:

```
class Base {}
class Derived : Base {}
```

... and a cast would still fail if you try to cast to `Derived` when you've actually got an instance of `Base`:

```
Base b = new Base();
Derived d = (Derived) b; // Exception
```

> I want my end user to need to make the conscious decision that the Foo is indeed a Bar and perform the cast before they are able to access the BarOp() method.

But the object *isn't* actually a `Bar`, otherwise the cast would work. Your plan would be sound if you ensured that you created *actual* `Bar` objects any time you should.

If you're not trying to add any execution-time safety, just make the developer say "I really mean to do this" then you could write a wrapper type:

```
class Bar : IBarOperations
{
     // Keep a reference to the existing Foo object
     // Expose privileged methods         
}
```

Then if you want to use a fluent style, you could write an instance or extension method for `Foo` of `AsBar()` which constructs a new `Bar`, leading to code of:

```
foo.AsBar().BarOp();
```

That still maintains the extra "check" (even though it's really not validation that the user *should* be able to do that) without trying to use casting.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to spell this one out, this has really clarified things for me. The `AsBar()` approach seems like it does what I'm looking for. I totally agree that this isn't any sort of real validation; I'm relying on a system of exceptions and error codes from the remote server (which is actually enforcing this) to ultimately prevent misuse. But being able to break those methods out into another class seemed worthwhile to me so as to not have all of the `Foo`s carrying around methods that 99% of them can't actually use.